# Continuous functions and the boundary

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I have some troubles with the next exercise.

> Let $(X,\tau_X)$ and $(Y,\tau_Y)$ be a topological spaces and $f:X\rightarrow Y$. Prove the equivalence between the next sentences.
>
> a) $f$ is continuous
>
> b) For all $A\subset X$, $f[\text{der}_X(A)]\subset\text{cl}_{Y}(f[A])$
>
> c) For all $B\subset Y$, $\text{Fr}_{X}(f^{-1}[B])\subset f^{-1}[\text{Fr}_{Y}(B)]$
>
> Here, $\text{der}$ is the derived set and $\text{Fr}$ is the boundary of a set.

a) $\Rightarrow$ b)

Let $A\subset X$. We know that $\text{der}_{X}(A)\subseteq\text{cl}_{X}(A)$, then, $f[\text{der}_{X}(A)]\subset f[\text{cl}_{X}(A)]$. Like $f$ is continuous, we know that $f[\text{cl}_{X}(A)]\subseteq\text{cl}_{Y}(f[A])$. Thus, $f[\text{der}_{X}(A)]\subset\text{cl}_{Y}(f[A])$

c) $\Rightarrow$ a)

Let $x\in X$ and $V\in \tau_{Y}$ (open set) such that $f(x)\in V$. By hypothesis, $$\text{Fr}_{X}(f^{-1}[Y\setminus V])\subset f^{-1}[\text{Fr}_{Y}(Y\setminus V)]$$

Like $V$ is open, then, $\text{Fr}_{Y}(Y\setminus V)\subseteq \text{cl}_{Y}(Y\setminus V)=Y\setminus V$, then, $$\text{Fr}_{X}(f^{-1}[Y\setminus V])\subset f^{-1}[Y\setminus V]$$Like $Y\setminus V$ is closed, then, $$f^{-1}[Y\setminus V]=f^{-1}[Y]\setminus f^{-1}[V]=X\setminus f^{-1}[V]$$ is closed. Then, $f^{-1}[V]$ is open and $x\in f^{-1}[V]$ and, finally, $f[f^{-1}[V]]\subseteq V$. Thus, $f$ is continuous.

But, how can I do it the implication b) $\Rightarrow$ c). I don't have idea. Some hint?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: For c) to a) you can also use that $A$ is closed iff $\operatorname{Fr}(A) \subset A$. Then $f^{1-}[Y \setminus V]$ is closed from the second equation already. Start with a closed set instead to simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (b)\implies (c): Let $x\in Fr_X(f^{-1}B).$

(i).  If $x\in f^{-1}B$ then $x\in der_X(X$ \ $f^{-1}B)$ so by (b), $$f(x)\in cl_Y(f(X \backslash f^{-1}B)=cl_Y(f(X) \backslash B)\subset cl_Y(Y \backslash B).$$ But also $f(x)\in B$ because $x\in f^{-1}B.$

So $f(x)\in B\cap cl_Y(Y$ \ $B)\subset cl_Y(B)\cap cl_Y(Y$ \ $B)= Fr_Y(B).$

So $x\in f^{-1}Fr_Y(B).$

(ii). If $x\not \in f^{-1}B$ then $x\in der_X(f^{-1}B)$ so by (b),  $f(x)\in cl_Y(f(B)).$

But  also $f(x) \in Y$ \ $B$ because $x\not \in f^{-1}B .$

So $f(x)\in cl_Y(B)\cap (Y$ \ $B)\subset cl_Y(B)\cap cl_Y(Y$ \ $B)=Fr_Y(B).$

So $x\in f^{-1}Fr_Y(B). $

Remark: (ii) is a dual of (i) because if we let $B'=Y$ \ $B$ then $Fr_Y(B)=Fr_Y(B').$ But also  $f^{-1}B$ and $f^{-1}B'$ are disjoint and their union is $X$, so $Fr_X(f^{-1}B)=Fr_X(f^{-1}B').$ So if we replace $B$ by $B'$ in (i) we have  $x\in f^{-1}B'\implies x\in f^{-1}Fr_Y(B')=Fr_Y(B).$ (.... And $x$ must belong to  $f^{-1}B$ or to  $f^{-1}B'$.)

Comment: There are many equivalent def'ns of continuity. I hadn't seen (c) before.